# Audacity often stops responding after installing newest Windows 10 updates

Tags: windows-10, audacity

My installation of Audacity 2.3.0 for Windows often (not always) stops responding (technically, stop accepting keyboard/mouse events, but the UI is not frozen) after Windows 10 got automatically updated in the past week (seems KB4586876 was installed during the update).

After uninstalling the update, the issue persists. This is a little bit strange to me. Have you seen such an issue? Any ideas how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Seems this issue is gone, 2 months after I posted the question. I can now use Audacity 2.3.0 on Windows 10 (2004) without any UI frozen issue.